# Manage many repetitive, CPU intensive tasks, running parallelly?

Tags: c#, performance, task, delay

I need to constantly perform 20 repetitive, CPU intensive calculations as fast as possible. So there is 20 tasks which contain looped methods in :

```
while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
```

to repeat them as fast as possible. All calculations are performed at the same time. Unfortunatelly this makes the program unresponsive, so added :

```
await Task.Delay(15);
```

At this point program doesn't hang but adding Delay is not correct approach and it unnecessarily slows down the speed of calculations. It is WPF program without MVVM. What approach would you suggest to keep all 20 tasks working at the same time? Each of them will be constantly repeated as soon as it finished. I would like to keep CPU (all cores) utilisation at max values (or near) to ensure best efficiency.

**EDIT**:
There is 20 controls in which user adjusts some parameters. Calculations are done in:

```
private async Task Calculate()
{
   Task task001 = null;
   task001 = Task.Run(async () => 
   {
      while (!CTSFor_task001.IsCancellationRequested)
      {
          await Task.Delay(15);
          await CPUIntensiveMethod();
      }
   }, CTSFor_task001.Token);
}
```

Each control is independent. Calcullations are 100% CPU-bound, no I/O activity. (All values come from variables) During calculations values of some UI items are changed:

```
 this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
     {
          this.lbl_001.Content = "someString";
     }));
```

Comment: Can you add the code you are using so far. Because multi threading in C#/WPF can be done in various ways and you are already talking about two different mechanisms (Tasks/Parallel).

Comment: Hard to give you anything without seeing how your code is currently structured. We can only make assumptions. Randomly awaiting a task to delay is pointless though.. it's all still going to run synchronously.

Comment: Also, what kind of work is there? Are the work items related? Are they really 100% CPU-bound, or is there I/O activity causing delays? What "hangs"? The UI? Or do only some of the tasks get their "fair" share of CPU? Do you want asynchronicity, or parallelism? `Task` is for asynchronicity, *not* parallelism, ie. it's designed to allow you many operations that aren't CPU-bound effectively to run at "the same time", without the extra costs of additional threads.

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit Please, don't change thread priorities manually. Just don't. It doesn't do what you think it does. See http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/08/thread-priorities-are-evil.html for more information :) Also, I expect that the OP doesn't actually run the work parallel to the UI anyway :)

Comment: Added code and additional description. @Luaan The UI of program hangs - not responsive. What I need is to calculate in background those CPU intensive, repetitive calculations at the same time using all cores.

Comment: Okay, so you should read up a bit on `await`+`async`. You obviously think they do something they don't. They are designed for operations that block without causing CPU usage (most often waiting for I/O of some kind). They're not magical "parallelism happens now" keywords. Your scenario doesn't warrant the use of `await`/`async` at all. In fact, the only properly async thing that happens in your code is the `await Task.Delay(15)` bit :) There's a few more things wrong with your code, but this is the crux of the issue. http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-using.html

Comment: @as74: I believe you would benefit from using the TPL Dataflow library.

Answer (score 7):

Let me just write the whole thing as an answer. You're confusing two related, but ultimately separate concepts (thankfully - that's why you can benefit from the distinction). Note that those are my definitions of the concepts - you'll hear tons of different names for the same things and vice versa.

Asynchronicity is about breaking the imposed synchronicity of operations (ie. op 1 waits for op 2, which waits for op 3, which waits for op 4...). For me, this is the more general concept, but nowadays it's more commonly used to mean what I'd call "inherent asynchronicity" - ie. the algorithm itself is asynchronous, and we're only using synchronous programming because we have to (and thanks to `await` and `async`, we don't have to anymore, yay!).

The key thought here is **waiting**. I can't do anything on the CPU, because I'm waiting for the result of an I/O operation. This kind of asynchronous programming is based on the thought that asynchronous operations are almost CPU free - they are I/O bound, not CPU-bound.

Parallelism is a special kind of the general asynchronicity, in which the operations don't primarily wait for one another. In other words, I'm not waiting, I'm **working**. If I have four CPU cores, I can ideally use four computing threads for this kind of processing - in an ideal world, my algorithm will scale linearly with the number of available cores.

With asynchronicity (**waiting**), using more threads will improve the apparent speed regardless of the number of the available logical cores. This is because 99% of the time, the code doesn't actually do any work, it's simply waiting.

With parallelism (**working**), using more threads is directly tied to the number of available work cores.

The lines blur a *lot*. That's because of things you may not even know are happening, for example the CPU (and the computer as a whole) is incredibly asynchronous on its own - the apparent synchronicity it shows is only there to allow you to write code synchronously; all the optimalizations and asynchronicity is limited by the fact that on output, everything is synchronous again. If the CPU had to wait for data from memory every time you do `i ++`, it wouldn't matter if your CPU was operating at 3 GHz or 100 MHz. Your awesome 3 GHz CPU would sit there idle 99% of the time.

With that said, your calculation tasks are CPU-bound. They should be executed using parallelism, because they are doing work. On the other hand, the UI is I/O bound, and it should be using asynchronous code.

In reality, all your `async Calculate` method does is that it masks the fact that it's *not* actually inherently asynchronous. Instead, you want to *run* it asynchronously to the I/O.

In other words, it's not the `Calculate` method that's asynchronous. It's the UI that wants this to run asynchronously to itself. Remove all that `Task.Run` clutter from there, it doesn't belong.

What to do next? That depends on your use case. Basically, there's two scenarios:

You want the tasks to always run, always in the background, from start to end. In that case, simply create a thread for each of them, and don't use `Task` at all. You might also want to explore some options like a producer-consumer queue etc., to optimize the actual run-time of the different possible calculation tasks. The actual implementation is quite tightly bound to what you're actually processing.

Or, you want to start the task on an UI action, and then work with the resulting values back in the UI method that started them *when the results are ready*. In that case, `await` finally comes to play:

```
private btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var result = await Task.Run(Calculate);

  // Do some (little) work with the result once we get it
  tbxResult.Text = result;
}
```

The `async` keyword actually has no place in your code at all.

Hope this is more clear now, feel free to ask more questions.

Answer (score 1):

So what you actually seek is a clarification of a good practice to maximize performance while keeping the UI responsive. As Luaan clarified, the `async` and `await` sections in your proposal will not benefit your problem, and `Task.Run` is not suited for your work; using threads is a better approach.

Define an array of Threads to run one on each logical processor. Distribute your task data between them and control your 20 repetitive calculations via [`BufferBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160414%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) provided in [`TPL DataFlow library`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

To keep UI responsive, I suggest two approaches:

1. Your calculations demand many frequent UI updates: Put their required update information in a queue and update them in Timer event.
2. Your calculations demand scarce UI updates: Update UI with an invocation method like `Control.BeginInvoke`

Answer (score 0):

As @Luaan says, I would strongly recommend reading up on `async`/`await`, the key point being it doesn't introduce any parallelism.

I *think* what you're trying to do is something like the simple example below, where you kick off `CPUIntensiveMethod` on the thread pool and await its completion. `await` returns control from the `Calculate` method (allowing the UI thread to continue working) until the task completes, at which point it continues with the `while` loop.

```
private async Task Calculate()
{
   while (!CTSFor_task001.IsCancellationRequested)
   {
       await Task.Run(CPUIntensiveMethod);
   }   
}
```